# How do I change the color of a span, when a specific button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="vote-stars number-0" method="get">
    <button id="1" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
    <button id="2" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
</span>

<br><br><br>

<span class="vote-stars number-1" method="get">
    <button id="1" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
    <button id="2" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
</span>
```

When a user clicks on a button, I want a Jquery code to run and change the color of that specific span inside the button.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $(this).find('span').css('color', 'orange'); But it gives error, and other solutions, i don't know.

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? Please edit the question to include your JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button onclick="$(this).children('span').css('color', 'red')">
```

I think is enough "onclick" to find children "span" and change color with ".css" function.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `on*` event attributes. If the OP had setup their jQuery logic correctly, there's no reason why it shouldn't have worked. This is a big step back.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed in your comment on the question works fine. You need to ensure that you've placed your jQuery logic within a document.ready event handler, and that the `click` event you've created is attached to the `button` elements. Also note that using inline `css()` calls should be avoided in favour of adding pre-defined CSS classes to your elements. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass('foo');
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<span class="vote-stars number-0" method="get">
    <button id="1" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
<button id="2" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
</span>

<br><br><br>

<span class="vote-stars number-1" method="get">
    <button id="1" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
<button id="2" class="submitUserVote"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></button>
</span>
```